# How to update Partial Value in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-update

I have a `table` like below...

| value | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Data-1 | Aarong |
| Data-125 | Aarong |
| INT-121 | Aarong |
| INT-122 | Aarong |

I would like to update `value` column with existing value. After update `value` column like below.

| value | Name |
| --- | --- |
| D-1 | Aarong |
| D-125 | Aarong |
| I-121 | Aarong |
| I-122 | Aarong |

Comment: What if you have `BLA-126` or `FOO-789`? Do you always want the first letter from the part before the dash?

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case, the simplest way is to execute two queries.

```
update table set data=replace(data,'Data-','D-') where position('Data-' in data) > 0;
```

and

```
update table set data=replace(data,'INT-','I-') where position('INT-' in data) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string always contain just one dash, you could do this with `split_part()`:

```
update mytable set value = 
    left(value, 1) || '-' || split_part(value, '-', 2)
```

if there may be more than one dash, and you want everything after the first:

```
update mytable set value = 
    left(value, 1) || substr(value, position('-' in value))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1402d4547619fe83e963bea907c75985)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace()`.  To see the new values:

```
select regexp_replace(value, '^(.).*(-.*)$', '\1\2')
from t;
```

You can interpret this as:

- `^` from the beginning of the string
- `(.)` take the first character and remember it.
- `.*` ignore any number of characters (until the following patter)
- `(-.*)` remember the hyphen and what follows
- `$` to the end of the string

The `'\1\2'` is the replacement, which is the first character and then the hyphen and everything afterwards.

To change them:

```
update t
    set value = regexp_replace(value, '^(.).*(-.*)$', '\1\2');
```

Regular expressions are quite powerful.  If you need to tweak the pattern matching rules, it is usually much simpler to adjust a regular expression than to deal with more cumbersome string operations.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a618fe46ac3452b55b1559dfee9744f5) is a db<>fiddle.